# Melhor maneira de projetar Classes a partir do banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software

Qual a melhor maneira de projetar as Classes a partir do esquema de Banco de dados abaixo:

```
Usuario(id INTEGER PK, desc TEXT);
Amigo(idA INTEGER, idB INTEGER, PK(idA,idB), FK(idA) REFERENCES Usuario(id));
```

Isso quer dizer que um usuario tem 0 ou mais amigos, ao projetar as classes nesse caso, estou inclinado a preferir ter somente uma classe Usuario e colocar amigos como um vetor, mas essa seria uma solução ruim por estar inconsistente com o BD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não acho uma solução ruim... na verdade é isso que muitos ORM recomendam quando na tabela intermediária não há nada além de duas FK, cada uma apontando para um elemento da relação.

Além disso, dessa forma a classe fica mais limpa, e o significado para quem vê fica mais claro.

Uma pessoa tem uma lista de amigos... simples.

A não ser que você queira qualificar as amizades (amizade boa, amizade ruim, amizade de infância, etc.), o que não é o caso presente, não acho que se deva complicar algo, só porque poderia ser de outra forma. Atenha-se aos fatos, no seu modelo amizades não são qualificadas e pronto. Se um dia isso mudar, vá la e altere as classes.